# errors trying to copy a binary search tree

Tags: c++, copy, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, copy-constructor

this is my copy constructor, overloaded assignment operator, and copy function, does anyone know why these 3 aren't working correctly?

**copy function:**

```
template <class T>
void BSTType<T>::copy(BTNodeType<T>*& node1, BTNodeType<T>* node2){
    if(node2==NULL)
        node1=NULL;
    else{
        node1=new BTNodeType<T>;
        node1->item=node2->item;
        copy(node1->left, node2->left);
        copy(node1->right, node2->right);
    }
}
```

**copy constructor that calls the copy function:**

```
template <class T>
BSTType<T>::BSTType(const BSTType<T>& tree){
    if(tree.root==NULL)
        root=NULL;
    else{
        copy(root, tree.root);
    }
}
```

**overloaded assignment operator which also calls the copy function:**

```
template <class T>
const BSTType<T>& BSTType<T>::operator=(const BSTType<T>& tree){
    if(this!=&tree){
        if(root!=NULL)
            destroy(root);
        if(tree.root==NULL)
            root=NULL;
        else
            copy(root, tree.root);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on "don't work correctly" (e.g., it doesn't compile? it doesn't work as it supposed to do during run-time?).

Comment: ok, the copy constructor works i just figured out! but for some reason the size of the new binary search trees isnt coming out right.

Comment: figured it out! sorry i wasted your time, I forgot to copy the count variable over from tree to tree. so i added count=tree.count to my copy constructor

Comment: Please post your explanation as an answer and mark the question as solved

Comment: I my company we call this role, the role of the "teddy bear" :-).